# Monadic logic with one binary relation is undecidable

Tags: logic, reference-request, computability

The following quote is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus):

> Adding a single binary relation symbol to monadic logic, however, results in an undecidable logic.

What would be a reference for this result?

Comment: See Boolos, Burgess and Jeffrey, *Computability & Logic* (2007), **Theorem 21.4** (The Church–Herbrand theorem). The satisfiability problem for the logic of a dyadic predicate is unsolvable. Proof at page 276.